# Why does my subdividsion surface looks weird?

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to rejust the edge or face to smoothy the shoulder(picture 2 is correct).When I add subdividsion surface on this model, he's shoulder always looks weird.

---

@John Eason: didn't work just like a broken bone.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Right-click > Shade Smooth in Object mode?

Comment: @JohnEason didn't work, still have irregular surface on shoulder, just like a broken bone.

Comment: You must have flipped normals or overlapping vertices or inner faces, check these 3 things

Comment: @moonboots thanks, i will check it.❤️

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @YousufChaudhry thanks a lot, i solved it. Changing the surface's rotation value was useful.